# Centos 6.10 непонятный процесс "mattud" который грузит сервер

Tags: centos6

Есть непонятный процесс под именем MATTUD который грузит сервер на столько, что достаточно что бы днем положить сервер намертво, пока нагрузка опять не упадет.

Хитрость его в том что он исчезает если запустить shell и диагностировать его через консоль не представляется возможным.

Пока он активный могу зайти в папку proc/PID/.

В папке /fd/ вот такие записи [image: папка FD]

Есть у кого то предложения что можно сделать в поиске корня зла?

Comment: /proc/PID/cmdline покажите

Comment: @andreymal, там все файлы с нулем, пустые т.е.

Comment: Если вы про размер файлов, то в /proc никогда не отображаются правильные размеры, так что /proc/PID/cmdline всё равно покажите даже если он с нулём

Comment: Он пустой, если его открывать редактором.. Смущает так же вот это "exe > /usr/sbin/mattud (deleted)"

Comment: Скачал к себе на комп. вот что внутри "tvjsw            "

Comment: Ну, по поведению это явно какой-то вирус, вероятно майнер. Но диагностировать его вот так через панельку и комменты как-то затруднительно

Comment: сбросил ключи и сменил пароль.. после перезапуска ssh, все равно появляется. Понимаю что скорее всего вирус, есть идеи чем его грохнуть? Из антивирусов только clam стоит

Comment: Он явно уже засел в системе, так что менять ключи и пароли определённо бессмысленно. Нужно найти бинарники вируса, удалить, прибить процессы и перезагрузиться, но так сходу я не знаю, как это всё грамотно провернуть

Comment: эх..пойду искать информацию дальше.

Comment: В общем, обратился к сисадминам РЕГРУ, у которых и стоит сервер.. нашли следы этого вируса который был загружен через уязвимость Exim. Вычистили процесс под названием "attu", он и запускал пакость заново. Нашли библиотеку ответственную за скрытие данных в консоли /usr/local/lib/libfwth.so.